# libGL.so running Qt Application draw colored polygons

Tags: 14.04, fglrx, qt5

[qt application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0QwR.png)

I have fglrx installed on Ubuntu 14.04. Programs run fine. Steam games are working. 
But when I try to open a Qt-App, it draws this colored polygons instead of interface. This program was working fine. It's just some kind of an issue probably with libgGL.so x64. Any ideas what might be causing it?

Comment: seems to be that it works fine if runned with sudo.